# How to access private files in s3 storage by laravel api for android application

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

Each user has a number of private files (photos, videos, etc.) stored on the s3 disk.
From the mobile application side, I send a request to Laravel web service to get the list of files and show it to the user on the client side.

I use the resource collection in Laravel to send responses and send my list to the mobile application.

My question is, how can I access the file itself using the file path on the client side?

Do I need to send a request to Laravel for each file to request a download type response for each file?

Considering that the number of files is more than one file and I want to show a list view inside the mobile application and I don't want to send a request to the server for each photo and download the photo.
I want the accessible links to be returned as soon as I get the list from the laravel app so that I can display them on the app side.

**Laravel Side:**

```
Route::get('api/user/{user}/files', function (User $user){
    $files = $user->files();
    return new FileCollection($files);
});


Route::get('api/download/{path}', function (string $path){
    return Storage::disk('s3')->download($path);
});
```

**Client Side:**

What do I do here?

Comment: Well you down't want your users to download all their files at once right ? You could easily allow them to download individual files by sending a download request each time they click a file in the list.

Comment: I did exactly that. Thank you for your answer
I thought that the temporaryUrl function should be connected to the s3 server in order to generate a public link for the file, but this is not the case and Laravel itself can create a public link for files with AWS-s3 packages and using the secret key and password received from the S3 service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($path, now()->addMinute())` to generate publicly accessible links for private files (links are going to expire in 1 minute in this example).

Comment: I did exactly that. Thank you for your answer
I thought that the temporaryUrl function should be connected to the s3 server in order to generate a public link for the file, but this is not the case and Laravel itself can create a public link for files with AWS-s3 packages and using the secret key and password received from the S3 service provider.